# "non-finite value supplied by optim" when using fitCopula

Tags: r

when I try to do an AIC test on different copulas, R keeps giving me this error message.

```
Error in optim(start, logL, lower = lower, upper = upper, method = optim.method,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim
```

but in my code, I didn't use the function optim and some give the other warnings.

```
Warning in fitCopula.ml(copula, u = data, method = method, start = start,  : possible convergence problem: optim() gave code=52
```

The error message gives the NA result while the warning message gives the number that seems on the right track.

here are my codes.

```
 AIC.result <- function(EC,copulafunction){
 AIC<- matrix(nrow=length(colnames(EC)),ncol=length(colnames(EC)),byrow=T)
 for (i in 1:length(colnames(EC))) {
   for (j in 1:length(colnames(EC))) {
     if(i==j){
       AIC[i,j] <-1
     }else{
       u <- pobs(as.matrix(EC[,i]))
        v <- pobs(as.matrix(EC[,j]))  
       fit<- fitCopula(copulafunction, cbind(u,v),method="ml")
       AIC[i,j] <-AIC(fit)
     }
   }
 }
  mean((AIC-length(colnames(EC)))/2)
 }
```

EC is the returns of different countries, and copulafunction is different type of copulas. And the Clayton copula and rotated Clayton copula give the error message while the rest gives the warning messages. The weirdest thing is in my case, EC contains 7 countries and it worked smoothly. When I applied to the DC which has 6 countries, the errors and warnings came. Is anyone know why?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You need to provide a little more detail to enhance the chances of getting useful answers. (i) indicate (`library(package)`) all the packages required to run the function; (ii) describe (`dput( )` or `str( )`) the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to only find the AIC for your model, then I think the `fitCopula` function returns it to you by default. If not then, the easy and direct way is to use the `BICopEst` function from the `R` package `VineCopula`. It returns the `AIC` and `BIC`. The error message is may due to fitting a wrong copula to your data, which sometimes leads the function to not converge, hence the error or warning. So, you should try another copula family. The best way to select the most appropriate copula for your data is to apply the `BICselect()` function in the `VineCopula` package. It will select the best bivariate copula among a wide range of a list based on AIC. Hence, it works for your case. Also, you can set another selection criteria supplied in the function.